# Could not resolve field 'Name' from <apex:inputField> value binding '{!cs.Name}' in page ProductCaseExternal

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment

Trying to build a webpage for teams to be able to submit cases and attachments. For some reason I am getting a "Could not resolve field 'Name' from  value binding '{!cs.Name}' in page ProductCaseExternal" error and even though I add the standard set controller I am still getting an error. Am I missing something on this for where I need to be adding this?

VF => ProductCaseExternal:

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="Case" extensions="attachController3" showheader="false" >
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/now-ui-kit/2e8e665f/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
        <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/now-ui-kit/2e8e665f/assets/css/now-ui-kit.min.css?v1.2.0" media="screen"/>
        <title>Submit a Case</title>
        <style>

            p, li, .description{
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.8rem;
            }

            .paddingTop{padding-top: 2rem;}
            }

            .background-black{background: #2196f3;}

            .background-black:hover, 
            .background-black:focus{background: #2386d3 !important;}      

            section .section-inner h2{color: #fff;}

            .round {
            border-radius: 100px;
            margin: 0;
            color: #9a9a9a
            }

            .longBox{height: 100px;}


            @media screen and (max-width: 500px){
            .brand .h1-seo{
            font-size: 2.2rem;
            }

            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <apex:form >
                <form class="form-signin"><br/><br/><br/>
                    <br/><h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create a Ticket</h2><br/><br/>
                    <h5 class="form-signin-heading">Email</h5><br/>
                    <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Email__c}" required="true"/>
                    <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Subject</h5><br/>
                    <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Subject}" required="true"/>
                    <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">What are you experiencing?</h5><br/>
                    <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.What_are_you_experiencing__c}" required="true"/>
                    <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Where is the location of your issue?</h5><br/>
                    <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Location_of_issue__c}" required="true"/>
                    <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Source Type</h5><br/>
                    <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control" value="{!case.Source_Type__c}" required="true"/>
                    <br/><h5 class="form-signin-heading">Description</h5><br/>
                    <apex:inputfield styleClass="inputGroupSelect01 custom-select form-control longBox" value="{!case.Description}" required="true"/><br/>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg background-black btn-round round " type="submit">Submit</button><br/><br/><br/>
                    <apex:pageBlock >

                        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                            <apex:commandButton id="uploadAttachment" value="Upload" action="{!uploadAttachment}"/>
                        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

                        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="theBlock">

                            <apex:inputField value="{!CS.CaseNumber}" id="bname"/>

                            <apex:repeat value="{!fileList}" var="fl">

                                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                                    <apex:outputLabel >Attachment</apex:outputLabel> 
                                    <apex:inputFile value="{!fl.body}" filename="{!fl.Name}" id="file" accept="docx, txt, xlsx, pdf" filesize="800" size="50" /> 
                                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                            </apex:repeat>

                        </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>
                        <apex:outputLabel >Please before you attach, click "Add File" to add the number of files you want to upload:&nbsp;&nbsp;</apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:commandButton id="AddAtt" value="Add File" action="{!AddAttachs}"/>

                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </form>
            </apex:form>
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Apex:

```
public class attachController3 {

public List<Attachment> fileList {get; set;}
public Case cs {get; set;}
public Attachment attach {get; set;}
public ApexPages.StandardSetController stdCntrlr {get; set;}
public attachController3(ApexPages.StandardController std){

}

public attachController3() {
    cs = new Case();

    attach = new Attachment();
    fileList = new List<Attachment>();
    fileList.add(attach);
    //AddAttachs();
}

public Case getCS(){
    if(cs == null) 
        cs = new Case();
    return cs; 
}

public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
    if(fileList == null) 
        fileList = new List<Attachment>();
    return fileList; 
}

public PageReference AddAttachs() {
    fileList.add(new Attachment());
    return null;
}

public PageReference uploadAttachment() { 
    insert cs;

    if(cs != null) {            
        List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();                               

        for(Attachment att : fileList)              
        { 
            if(att.name != null && att.body != null)
                attachments.add(new Attachment(parentId = cs.Id, name = att.name, body = att.body)) ;                
        }
        if(attachments != null){
            upsert attachments;                 
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, attachments.size() + ' file(s) uploaded successfully'));                                              
        }else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error uploading file'));
        }              
    }                    

    return null;      
}   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Case object and `Case` don't have `Name` field. You need to use `CaseNumber` instead. CaseNumber is an AutoNumber field so you won't edit it either.

Comment: I updated that to CaseNumber but I am now getting an error "Unknown property 'CaseStandardController.contentType'"

Comment: @JoshuaAnderson because you are using `contentType` on VF page but you have not declared it.  Declare a public [property in class name `contentType`

Comment: I updated the code above and I am getting no errors but it also doesn't seem to be working. The code that I found online that I was trying to use was supposed to allow an external user on a site be able to add however many files that they are wanting and then submit a case after that. When I go to select add it errors out and when I go to submit the case it is not creating the case. Is there anything on this code that you might see that is causing this issue?